# Liberar acesso no diretório do WordPress para imprimir imagens? .htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, htaccess

Estou com um problema no WordPress, estou fazendo o upload das imagens num diretório específico e preciso que essas imagens sejam visualizadas diretamente pela URL.

A partir da raiz do portal existe um diretório chamado server e dentro dele tem um diretório chamado imagens, então o acesso seria:

```
http://www.meusite.com/server/imagens/minhafoto.jpg
```

Porém, o WordPress não permite o acesso direto a esse diretório, conforme exemplo acima, apresenta erro 404.

Como libero essa regra no `.htaccess` do WordPress?

Segue meu .htaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso não é um problema do WordPress, como o colega falou acima o WP não bloqueia o acesso direto a esse tipo de arquivo. Essa imagens aparecem no seu site? Já tive problema parecido quando as imagens não tinha permissão de leitura no servidor, mas no meu caso o retorno era 403 e não 404, tem certeza que os arquivos existem né? Se sim, então checa as permissões de escrita ou entra em contato com o suporte do servidor.

Answer (score 5):

Se está mostrando página não encontrada, é porque o arquivo não existe, wordpress não restringe acesso as pastas a não ser que você configure isso explicitamente no .htaccess, essa configuração padrão do wordpress não afeta isso.

Por padrão você consegue acessar todos os *assets* diretamente. (.css,.js,.png, etc.).

Comment: Porém, existe ainda o problema e o arquivo existe.

Comment: Te garanto que há algum problema com o endereço que você está acessando, se a imagem existisse e você só tem essa configuração no .htaccess, deveria exibir pelo menos "Permission denied" caso fosse algum problema de permissão ou a imagem seria exibida.

Poste a URL real e o diretório real e a configuração do diretório do seu servidor web.

Comment: De fato Erico, era um problema na URL mesmo, consegui fazer aparecer a imagem. mUITO OBRIGADO.

Comment: Sem problema. por favor marque a pergunta como resolvida para que ela não apareça mais em "Sem reposta"